# Unable to get href links from webscrape Powershell

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I'm working on scraping href links from specific portion of website.
Im looking to get links for specific news Ttile, not the whole site.

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.livesquawk.com/latest-news
$title = ($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('div') | Where { $_.ClassName -match 'latest_news_each_title'}).InnerText
```

Confused..

```
$link = ($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('div') or should it be ('a')?
```

I appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that page, not every article has a link. We need to be able to correlate the links to the articles. Examining under the hood we can see each article is grouped together by classname `latest__news__each`. We can use this combined with regex and a switch statement to grab the required components.

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.livesquawk.com/latest-news

$WebResponse.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName('latest__news__each') | foreach {
    switch -Regex ($_.innerhtml -split "`n"){
        'latest_news_each_title>' {$title = $_ -replace '.+>(.+?)</DIV>','$1'}
        'latest_news_each_time' {$time = $_ -replace '.+>(.+?)</div>.+','$1'}
        '<A href=' {$link = $_  -replace '.+A href="(.+?)".+','$1'}
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        News = $title
        Time = $time
        Link = $link
    }
    $title,$time,$link = $null
}
```

The text is considered one long string which is why `-Split "`n"` was used to separate each by new line. From there if the line matches specific criteria, we apply a regex replace to pull out just the desired data. It's important at the end to $null the properties out so info from the previous run doesn't accidentally go in the next object.